# How can I parse a string to extract numbers with a regular expression using NSRegularExpression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, macos, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I am new to regular expressions and have no clue how to work with them. I wanted to create a regex for the below piece of text to fetch the min, avg & max time. I would be using them with NSRegularExpression to fetch the range & then the string.

Can someone please help in creating a regex for the below text.

```
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.073/6.010/13.312/2.789 ms
```

Comment: What's the regular expression you have come up with so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Break it down.

I'm assuming you want to get the numeric values out of that string and toss the rest.

First make a regexp to match a number:

- `\d` matches a digit
- `\d*` matches zero or more digits
- `\.` matches a period
- `(\d*\.\d*)` matches zero or more digits, then a period, then zero or more digits

Then turn it into a Cocoa string:

- `@"(\\d*\\.\\d*)"`

Then make an [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d*\\.\\d*)"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
```

Then get an array with all the matches:

```
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                              options:0
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Then pull out the values:

```
NSString* minText = [string substringWithRange:[matches[0] range]];
NSString* avgText = [string substringWithRange:[matches[1] range]];
// etc.
```

I leave it as an exercise to convert these strings into floats. :-)

---

**Update:** I found myself so nauseated by the complexity of this that I made a little library I am humbly calling [Unsuck](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck) which adds some sanity to `NSRegularExpression` in the form of `from` and `allMatches` methods. Here's how you'd use them:

```
NSRegularExpression *number = [NSRegularExpression from: @"(\\d*\\.\\d*)"];
NSArray *matches = [number allMatches:@"3.14/1.23/299.992"];
```

Please [check out the unsuck source code on github](https://github.com/alexch/unsuck) and tell me all the things I did wrong :-)

Comment: I am almost not mentioning this because it is unrelated to the correctness of this solution, but just because it is always good to use correct terminology: @"(\\d*\\.\\d*)" is a `NSString*`, not a `C string`. `C string`s are `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want a regex, and they are very handy to learn, but it might be a bit heavier lifting than you need for this situation. With that in mind, I am providing an alternative. I am sure someone else will give you a regex as well.

```
NSString* str = @"round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.073/6.010/13.312/2.789 ms";

NSString* str2 = [str substringFromIndex:32];

NSArray* components = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

CGFloat min = [[components objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
CGFloat avg = [[components objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
CGFloat max = [[components objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];

NSLog(@"min/avg/max: %f/%f/%f",min,avg,max);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by using `(.*) = (.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.*)`